# Android SVG and installed APK szie

Tags: android, performance, svg, apk

I have an app which APK size is 4 MB but after install it grows to 50 MB.

The app has:
- svg files
- Dagger 2
and other DI libraries.

I know that the APK has compressed files but  I'm trying to find out why the difference is so big.

Does the use of SVG files increments the size of the app ones it has been installed?

does this line use to reduce the size?

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: "but after install it grows to 50 MB" -- how precisely are you measuring this?

Comment: you are comparing different numbers.

Comment: @CommonsWare I do install it in my mobile phone then I check the settings of the app.